# MultiSelect Widget

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am implementing the following jQuery plugin jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget all works ok.

But when I load a form/page with some sections already selected it does not show/represent this in the visual of the widget, when I remove the widget it show the actual selected items on load.

Has anyone come across this and have a solution.

on load I have the following select set EG:

```
  <select name="example-presets" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4" selected="selected">Option 4</option>
  </select>
```

No when i load the page with out the plugin the select will show the 'selected="selected"' options but when I impliment the plug in and then reload the pag, then click on the open link all the  'selected="selected"'  items do not show as being selected, all the checkboxes are unchecked.

I am trying to achove the following but does not seem to want to play:
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/preselected.htm

The selected options are generated using php and are not static like this EG thou.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please narrow down the problem and post the code where you suspect the bug might lie?

Answer (score 0):

Well after a little investigation it seems the current code that I used was UI Widget 1.14pre so looking at their example I noticed their version is UI Widget 1.13 so i used this version instead and all worked well.

many Thanks